# Jquery, Javascript click && value

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, click, int

how do I check inside jquery if a button is clicked and if the variable test has an integer of 1?
I have done this so far.

```
$(".bx-next").click(function() && (test == 1){
    $("#step_1").text("Hello world!");
});
```

Comment: this is not correct syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking about `click` wrong. It means "**When** the button is clicked". It isn't a condition that you are testing for at the time the code runs. It is setting up an event handler to run later.

So you need to rethink your test:

> if a button is clicked and if the variable test has an integer of 1?

Should be:

When a button is clicked, if test is 1.

```
$(".bx-next").click(function() {
    if (test == 1) {
        $("#step_1").text("Hello world!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You would want to add an additional `if` statement after the function is called.

```
$(".bx-next").click(function(){
    if (test == 1){ // Perform test
        $("#step_1").text("Hello world!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
clicked  = false;
$(".bx-next").click(function(){
    $("#step_1").text("Hello world!");
clicked = true;
});
if(clicked &&  (test == 1)) {
// do code
}
```